# How to display only torrents which are currently downloading/uploading?

Tags: rtorrent

I'm using rTorrent 0.9.2/0.13.2. I haven't found such tab on 1-0 buttons, and searching in Google doesn't provide any useful links. Is it something I must setup myself in the configuration?

**Update:**
To put it more clerarly:

```
 Yes Studio Discography 1969-1972
            1308.0 / 10191.2 MB Rate:   0.0 /   0.0 KB Uploaded:  1027.5 MB [12%] --d --:-- [T  R: 0.79]
```

There is 0.0 / 0.0 KB, this torrent is not downloading or uploading right now. I need to list torrents that have some number in current upload/download speed rather than 0.0 / 0.0 KB. That's what I mean by downloading/uploading torrents.

Comment: I've also looked for this feature, and I do not believe it is possible in rTorrent.  I'd settle for sorting by transfer speed or number of connected peers, but that feature is also apparently unavailable.  One thing I have done on occasion is run multiple instances of rTorrent to separate any long-running transfers from day-to-day stuff.  That does clear up the screen a bit.

Comment: The terminology most clients seem to use is "active" downloads

Comment: @Journeyman Geek That's right, and rTorrent even has an "active" tab at 0 key, but surprisingly there's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Which is why it (the defective "active"-tab) is in the "open issues"-list (for over 9 months!) See [here](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/issues/117).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your config:

```
view_sort_current = active,greater=d.get_up_rate=
schedule = filter_active,12,20,"view_filter = active,\"or={d.get_up_rate=,d.get_down_rate=}\" ;view_sort=active"
```

Comment: so rakhasa just closes the ticket

Answer (score 1):

For 0.9+

```
schedule2 = filter_active,30,30,"view.filter = active,\"or={d.up.rate=,d.down.rate=}\""
```